# Java(FX) UI Update and (background) download task

Tags: java, javafx, concurrency, synchronization

i wrote a small application, which among other things makes a REST call to a JIRA REST API do download issues. I have a progress bar indicating the progress of the download. However, actually i need to make two REST calls. The first one needs to finished before the second one starts. Between them i need to update the UI.

Below is some example code:

```
// Loads the dialog from the fxml file and shows it
@FXML
public void showProgressDialog() {
    mainApp.showDownloadProgressDialog();
}

// Retrieves some meta information
public void firstDownload() {
    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() {
            // do something
        }
    };
    new Thread(task).start();
}
// Do some UI update

// Retrieves the actual issues
public void secondDownload() {
    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() {
            for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
                // so something
                updateProgress((double) i / (double) limit, max);
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(task).start();
}
// Do some UI update
```

How can i ensure that all functionality shown above is executed in exactly this order?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How are the 2 methods starting the tasks called? Why can't you combine them to a single `Task`?

Comment: Thanks, a now found a solution with only one Task!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `EcecutorService` with a single thread to control the scheduling:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

service.submit(task1);
service.submit(task2);

// shutdown after last submitted task
service.shutdown();
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried that also, and it helped me to solve a similar problem!